# concatenate each row of a list with the rows of another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
liste1 = ['a','b','c']
liste2 = ['1','2','3']
```

I want to get a list made from concatenating the rows of `liste1` with the rows of the same index of `liste2`:

```
list = ['a1','b2','c3']
```

How to do that in python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way would be using `zip`:

```
>>> [i + j for i, j in zip(liste1, liste2)]
['a1', 'b2', 'c3']
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists have the exact same length, you could do :

```
new_list = [liste1[i]+liste2[i] for i in len(liste1)]
```